# Defining a complex root function on an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Looking at a domain which is like an annulus (inner radius $r$ and outer radius $s>r$) can there be a (square)root function defined on it?

If it can't be single valued, is it possible to define one which is not single valued?

Comment: Do you mean a *single-valued* square root?

Comment: the brief answer is no, not single valued if the origin is in the middle. In fact, Volume I of John B. Conway, page 202, Theorem VIII.2.2(h) a region $G$ is simply connected if and only if every analytic  $f \in H(G)$ such that $f(z) \neq 0 \; \;  \forall z \in G,$ there exists a $g \in H(G)$ such that $f(z) = \left( g(z) \right)^2.$ I believe $H(G)$ must mean holomorphic and single-valued, have not found the definition yet. Got it, page 151, section VII.2.